# AddStudent() method will not maintain a name variable

Tags: java, arrays, variables, search

I'm creating a program that will act as an enrollment register, allowing the user to add and delete students from a course, search for students, report on student data and save these to a file. The reason I am posting again on the site is because my `AddStudent()` method doesn't seem to maintain a student name variable. For instance, my search method searches the student array where the data is stored and prints the searched for students data, or at least it should but when you add more than one student the name variable changes to that of the most recently inputted student thus printing every student as it thinks that they all have the same names. It also does this for my save method, it saves the student data in a file but all with the same name, none of the other data is duplicated. So far I have this:

```
public static void AddStudent() {

        String sName = null;
        String dateOB = null;
        String address = null;
        String GENDER = null;

        // create student object
        Student studentToAdd = new Student(sName, dateOB, address, GENDER);
        // read in name and update student 
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println ("Type Student Name: ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        Student.Name = name;

        // read in and validate date of birth
        Scanner scannerDOB = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("Type Student Date of Birth : ");
        String dateOfBirth = scannerDOB.nextLine();
        studentToAdd.DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;

        // read in address
        Scanner scannerAdd = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("Type Student Address: ");
        String address1 = scannerAdd.nextLine();
        studentToAdd.Address = address1;

        // read in gender - validate against you're constant?
        Scanner scannerGen = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("Type Student Gender\n M for Male \n F for Female: ");
        String gender = scannerGen.nextLine();
        studentToAdd.Gender = gender;

        // Add to the array in the last free location
        Students [nextFreeLocation] = studentToAdd;
}
```

Comment: Where is the Students array defined and where is the nextFreeLocation defined?

Comment: Please remove all mention of deadlines as that has nothing to do with the question itself, really is not our concern, and may increase down-votes on your question. Regarding your code, I have to wonder if your program needs to be re-structured such as by making a School class that has a non-static Student[] array and a non-static `public void addStudent(Student student)` method that has no user interaction within it. The user interaction code should go elsewhere.

Comment: Question edited and mentions of deadline have been removed.

Comment: Are you sure what is getting stored in the `studentToAdd` variable is all correct as what you have entered?

Comment: I think so, I have referenced all of the variable back to the constructor variables of the student class. Im also incrementing the nextFreeLocation after calling the method if that helps?

Comment: to be 100% sure that the `studentToAdd` variable is storing the data correctly then you could use `System.out.println()` method after each property is set to the variable. i.e. after say the line `studentToAdd.Name = name;` You could check it by adding `System.out.println(studentToAdd.Name);`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you radically re-design your program including:

- Creating a Course class that holds an `ArrayList<Student>` (not an array), say called `students`.
- Giving this class a public non-static `public void addStudent(Student student)` method that allows outside classes the ability to add Students to Course's students List.
- Have your user interface (UI) code, including all code that uses Scanner, separate from the Course code.
- Yes, the UI code can also have a non-static `addStudent` method, where it gets Student information from the user, creates a Student object and then calls Course's `addStudent(...)` method.
- Have a separate class for saving and uploading data to and from your file(s).

Of course all of this will depend on your assignment requirements, and if any of these suggestions run afoul of those, please let me know.

Comment: I feel that this guy does not have an UI that is why he is using `Scanner`

Comment: @Blip: He has a console UI, which is a UI, albeit a primitive one.

Comment: @Blip I believe you meant GUI?

Comment: @bot Yes and now I understood what is wrong in my comment